# Creating two different headers-- sticky/scrolling and a top one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With my current code, the white bar header is at the top when the page loads up. When you scroll, it fades, and when you scroll to the top, the white header is back. So I've made some progress.
What I'm trying to get is for there to be a transparent header when the scroll is at the top: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr2rH.png)

And for the white bar header, the main one, to be sticky and follow all the way down, like this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgJVw.png)
and when you scroll back up, for it to fade back to the transparent header.

CSS:

```
#header{position:fixed;
       left:0;top:0;right:0;height:106px;z-index:100;
    -webkit-transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out
}
#header .logo{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:162px;height:106px}
#header .logo a{display:block;position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;
                margin:-30px 0 0 -60px;width:120px;height:60px;
                text-indent:-99999px;
                background-image:url("header_logo.png")}
#header.scroll{border-bottom:1px solid #ededed;background:#fff;} /* so this is the transparent header?
#header.scroll .logo a{background-image:url("header_logo_transp.png")}
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var sc = $(window).scrollTop()
   if (sc == 0) {
   $("#header").addClass("scroll");
   //document.removeElementbyId(header); when I put this line in, the header wasn't there when the page first loads up-- kind of what I want, but I want the secondary header to be up there when sc==0
   } 
   else {
   $("#header").removeClass("scroll");

    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header" class="scroll" style="top: 0px;">
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">WEBSITE</a></h1>
        <a href="#" title="Menu" class="btn_menu"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having may be due to the nature of 'scroll'. It doesn't get every single pixel value. Changing your if statement a little to include 1 as a check will help ensure the classes are added and removed when they should be.

Example: https://codepen.io/SROwl/pen/Mdbwpy

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav top">Nav Top</div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
body {
  background: #000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 4000px;
}
.nav {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  transition:  250ms ease;
  &.top {
    color: #fff;
    background: transparent;
  }
  &.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
var  winTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
  if (winTop >= 1) {    
    $('.nav').addClass('fixed').removeClass('top');
  } else if (winTop <= 0) {    
    $('.nav').addClass('top').removeClass('fixed');    
  }
})
```